# Drupal image styles DivisionByZeroError

Tags: drupal

I have a fresh Drupal 10 installation and I am trying to create a new image style, whenever I edit an image style (new or a default Drupal one) I get this error:

`DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in template_preprocess_image_style_preview() (line 77 of core/modules/image/image.admin.inc).`

Adding some logging to core/modules/image/image.admin.inc reveals there is no "derivative" key on `$variables['preview']`.

I am using PHP8.2 and NGINX on Ubuntu 22 Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: It's likely that the creation of the derivative image failed, which could be due to a permission issue in the files/styles directory.

Comment: I've tried generating the derivatives using this module  https://www.drupal.org/project/image_styles_generator, I get no errors and it says there are no derivatives to generate.  I've also set the whole project directory permissions to 777 to be certain there are no permission issues and I still get the error.